# Mqtt-client JAVA + user interface

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de implementar un código que use el protocolo MQTT en Java, actualmente vengo de C++ y hace mucho tiempo no programo (Motivos de universidad), pero necesito retomar con un pequeño proyecto en JAVA y que mejor de una ves que recordar mi conocimiento en POO y finalizarme en JAVA de buena manera. Mi código usando MQTT con librerías PAHO, se suscribe a un tema y funciona bien pero, necesito que el resultado no me lo muestre en la consola, si no en un panel con JFrame o bueno, así lo he pensado la idea es que se muestre en interfaz gráfica y no en consola, y la vdd no sé como hacerlo. Espero puedan colaborarme

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;


public class Ventana2 extends JFrame implements MqttCallback{

    MqttClient clienteJava;
    MqttConnectOptions connectOptions;

    static final String topic = "Temperatura";    
    static final String Broker = "tcp://iotmosquitto.cloudapp.net:1883";
    static final String ClientID = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    static final Boolean Pub = true;
    static final Boolean Subs = true;

    JPanel Panel;
    JLabel Texto;

    // connectionLost se invoca apenas la conexión se pierda
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable thrwbl) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        System.out.println("Se ha perdido la conexíón");

        //Código para reconectar podría ir aquí.
    }

    // messageArrived se invoca cuando un suscriptor del tópico ha recibido el mensaje
    @Override    
    public void messageArrived(String Topico, MqttMessage Message) throws Exception {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        String mensaje = new String(Message.getPayload());
        System.out.println(mensaje);        

    }

    // deliveryComplete se invoca cuando el broker ha recibido exitosamente un mensaje       publicado por este cliente
    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }

    public void ventana(String mensaje){
        Panel = new JPanel();
        Texto = new JLabel();

        this.add(Panel);
        Panel.add(Texto);
        Texto.setText(mensaje);
    }

    public void ejecutaCliente(){
        // preparando un cliente MQTT

        connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();        
        connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
        connectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(50);        
        //MqttTopic Topico = clienteJava.getTopic(topic);

        //conexion al broker
        try{
            clienteJava = new MqttClient(Broker, ClientID);
            clienteJava.setCallback(this);
            clienteJava.connect(connectOptions);

        }catch(MqttException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Ha sido conectado al broker " + Broker);

        // Preparando un tópico
        //MqttTopic Topico = clienteJava.getTopic(Topico);

        try{
                int subQoS = 1;
                clienteJava.subscribe(topic,subQoS);
        }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Cristhian. Por favor ten presente que en este sitio el idioma oficial es español. Si quieres publicar preguntas en inglés, deberás ir al sitio https://stackoverflow.com. Si quieres que tu pregunta se mantenga "on topic" en este sitio, por favor traduce su contenido a español.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, la verdad es que soy nuevo en stackoverflow y desconocía de ello, ya he traducido el texto.

Answer (score 1):

El problema radicaba en usar hilos, pues se ejecutan varios procesos, y sin usarlos funciona pero no se está ejecutando el programa adecuadamente, para ellos simplemente he adecuado el programa de mejor manera, a quien le interese puedo dar el código.

Comment: A la comunidad le interesa una idea de la naturaleza de los problemos de hilos que tuviste y como lo solucionaste. Sientete invitado de ampliar tu respuesta. También lo puedes aceptar. Es un tema interesante porque Swing no es "threadsafe" del principio. Me imagino que el proyecto completo podría ser demasiado amplio para una respuesta, pero algunas muestras de código critico con comentarios serían maravillosos.